# Redis TimeoutException

Tags: c#, .net, redis

I'm pushing some data to a Redis instance from a console app every few seconds. This is roughly how I'm doing it:

```
            int foo = GetFoo();
            BigObject bar = GetBigObject();

            _cache.StringSet("Foo", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo));
            _cache.StringSet("Bar", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bar));
```

but after a while I get an exception:

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: 'Timeout performing SET
> RtSignal-op (5000ms), inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, rs:
> CompletePendingMessage, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 5, out-pipe: 0,
> serverEndpoint: Unspecified/localhost:5002, mgr: 9 of 10 available,
> clientName: SVGD0083, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=16,Max=1000),
> WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=32764,Min=16,Max=32767), v: 2.0.593.37019 (Please
> take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that
> can cause timeouts:
> https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)'

In the linked to page there is a suggestion that the issue might be a result of `Thread Theft` and the solution is to include the following line:

```
ConnectionMultiplexer.SetFeatureFlag("preventthreadtheft", true);
```

The problem is that there doesn't seem to exist a `SetFeatureFlag` method in .NET framework.

Any ideas?

Comment: Migrate to .NET 5?

Comment: This helped me, I did not have targetFramework in my httpRuntime tag in my web.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/993854/all-redis-commands-timing-out-when-using-azure-cac.html

Answer (score 3):

What is the *size* of your objects? If `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo)` is returning a 500MB string, then yes: you're going to have a bad day.

Also, what else is the server doing? This needs a little digging at the server, but: the redis `SLOWLOG` command gives you information into long-running operations. If anything is taking serious time (I'd start to get twitchy at anything that takes more than say 10 milliseconds), then *your server is essentially stalling*, which needs to be investigated - but that's not something the library can fix.

If you're talking to a far away server, you may want a larger timeout.

Finally, I very much doubt that this particular scenario is related to thread-theft; if anything, that sounds like you're clutching at straws (metaphorically). But if `ConnectionMultiplexer.SetFeatureFlag` doesn't exist, you're probably using an old library version. So: what library version *are* you using?

Comment: Thank you for your input! Much appreciated. The object is not even close to 500MB. A few Kb at the most. Redis is running in docker, and the client writing the data is just calling StringSet every few seconds. Both client and Redis is running on the same machine. It's actually been running quite a while without the error popping up, a few hours maybe

Answer (score 0):

StackExchange.Redis is not part of the .net framework.

_cache probably is the StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase object type.
So, just add the line where you initialize redis support at your application - probably at startup.cs.